# Absolute path error when building wheel

Tags: python, django, python-wheel

**OVERVIEW**

I'm trying to learn how to build wheels on my windows dev box so hopefully I'll have a nice way to deploy django websites on linux boxes. But right now I'm stuck with a little error.

Here's my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='pkg',
      version="1.0",
      packages=find_packages(),
      data_files=[('/etc/nginx/sites-available', ['foo.conf'])]
      )
```

When i try to do `>python setup.py bdist_wheel` I'm getting this error:

```
raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname
```

It seems the way I'm using data_files is not supported.

**QUESTION**

What's the right way to deploy config files using [wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) & [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wheels should be used for bundling Python code. It's not for configuration management (where Nginx configurations would typically be handled).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34204582/116042

Comment: Ok, got it! at first it didn't sound right having config stuff on wheels but thanks for the confirmation ;D